# Duplicate cell in a static UITableViewCell at indexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a static `UITableViewCell`. In the storyboard, when you select a section and add another cell (in the attribute inspector,) then it duplicates the last row in that section, and adds it to the `tableView`. Is there a way to do that programamatically?

Basically what I'm trying to do, is copy a cell at a `indexPath`, (with all it's subviews,) then paste it right under that cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't copy a cell. Neither UITableViewCell, not any of it's superclasses conforms to NSCopying. If you need to add more cells dynamically (in code), it would be better to use dynamic prototypes. You add a new cell by adding another element to the array that you use to populate the table, and call reloadData.

Comment: Is it possible to make one section in the tableView dynamic prototype cells?

Comment: @MikeRally, not sure what you mean. Do you mean one section dynamic and one static? If so, no, you can't do that. However, there's nothing that you can do with a static table view that you can't do with a dynamic one, so why not do it all dynamic?

Comment: Good point. What should I do about `cellForRow...`. if I have more than one cell id?

Comment: @MikeRally, you just dequeue the one you want based on the indexPath in an if-else block. Each cell type should have a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes. If you look in the header for UITableViewCell, it implements **NSCoding**. So, in your custom subclass of **UITableViewCell**, implement the **NSCoding** protocol classes and encode / decode your custom attributes in it. Make sure that you set all the attributes of the cell inside **initWithCoder**: method such that it looks similar to the cell that you have. Then, when you reload the table or insert tableView cell, simply archive and unarchive the cell you want to use, to create a copy of it. And you have the same cell.

```
@interface MyCustomClass: UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *myBackground;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *text;

@end

@implementation MyCustomClass

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        self.myBackground = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"myBackground"];
        self.text = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"myTitle"];

       self.contentView.backgroundColor = self.myBackground;
       self.titleLabel.text = self.text;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [super encodeWithCoder:aCoder];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.myBackground forKey:@"myBackground"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.text forKey:@"myTitle"];
}

@end
```

Then, some where in your tableView data source **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method, simply copy the cell you want and return it like this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
   ...
   ...
    if (self.shouldCopyCell) {
      UITableViewCell *cellToCopy = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathToCopyCellFrom];
       NSData *copiedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:cellToCopy];
       UITableViewCell *newCell = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:copiedData];
       return newCell;
    }
  ...
}
```

Having said that, I am not quite sure if you should really do this, Since, you can create exact same looking cell with the same method, that you did for the original cell :)